# Fourier transform of a Gaussian in Excel returns imaginary coefficients

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, gaussian

I am using Fourier Analysis tool in Excel to transform a Gaussian $\exp(-x^2)$ on a uniform and symmetric grid of $x$ values.  I am expecting the result to contain only real numbers (which should furthermore look like a Gaussian), but what I get is a collection of complex coefficients. I am at a loss. A Fourier transform of a Gaussian should be another Gaussian, why complex coefficients? How to get from them expected Gaussian?

Comment: @MBaz Thank you, the answer in that post does indeed answer why coefficient came out complex. However, I still get coefficients which are negative, when  I was expecting only real positive (non-negative) ones.

Comment: The question, as asked, has been answered in another question so I have closed this.  Please edit your question if the real question was about negative values, not complex ones.

Comment: @Confounded It may be due to windowing. Make sure that $x$ covers a wide range (try something like -30 to 30).

Comment: @MBaz Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be windowing: I extended to +/- 30, but some of the Fourier coefficients still come out negative. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried to do Fourier analysis in Excel to replicate your results but it's just too painful. Unless you have a pressing reason to use Excel, you can use any number of free tools like Julia, SciPy, SciLab or Octave.

Comment: @MBaz There is a tool called Fourier Analysis in the Excel's Data Analysis toolbox, and the only input is just a (power-of-two length) vector of observations. So, I sued a vector of 1024 equally-spaced points in [-30,30) which there then used as an input into a Gaussian $\exp(-x^2)$ which then is used as an input into that Fourier Analysis tool.

Comment: That's what I tried to do, and what I found too painful. Doing this in any of the tools I mentioned takes three lines of code.

Comment: @MBaz OK, I found the answer: Excel expects the input to be ordered in the same way as the output it produces: from $0$ to $N/2-1$ and then from $–N/2$ to $-1$. Apparently, the same is true for Matlab's function `fft`, so that `X = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(x)))` need to be applied to a "normally" order input (i.e one going from $-N/2$ to $N/2-1$) to first reorder it, then apply transform, and then reorder it again.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

A delayed or offset Gaussian would have complex coefficients. I suspect that the $x=0$ point you are assuming is not where Excel assumes. The magnitude would have a Gaussian shape and the phase would be Linear,  which you can use as a diagnostic. Gaussian is also infinite in extent so, there is going to be some effects due to truncation.

The issue that confuses most people is that the DFT has the character of "assuming" that it is operating on one period of a periodic sequence. In your case the Gaussian is symmetric around $x=0$ but the first point in the sequence corresponds to $x=0$ so where do the values for $x<0$ go? They go with the next cycle of the sequence so if the period has $N$ data points, depending if $N$ is odd  or even the periodic portion corresponding to $x<0$ would be in the samples from $N/2$ to $N-1$.